# Numbering Bars from 1- 5 In pine editor and it should reset every day at midnight

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart

how do I number each bar 1-5 in pine editor? So, it should reset after midnight so 12am should always be 1. When the number reaches 5 the number will reset and the next bar will be a 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hour` and `minute` built-in variables to work with any time.

```
//@version=5
indicator("a")
h = input.int(00, "Hour")
m = input.int(00, "Minute")
l = input.int(5, "Limit")

var cnt = 1

time_reset = hour == h and minute == m

if (time_reset)
    cnt := 1
else
    if (cnt % l == 0)
        cnt := 1
    else
        cnt := cnt + 1
        
plotchar(time_reset ? 1 : na, "Time Reset", "•", location.absolute, color.green, size = size.small)
plot(cnt)
```

[image]